# Unused exports added in webpack bundles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, webpack

I have setup entries in webpack config as

```
entry: {
    // main: './src/index.js',
    analytics: './src/analytics/index.js',
  };
```

since the main entry is commented out I expected some modules not to be included in the bundle but were still being added. It turns out both entries eventually import some stuff from a file that re-exports a lot of the unwanted and wanted modules.
Why aren't such unused exports excluded from the bundle?

After going through the tree-shaking documentation I can confirm that

- We use ES2015 module syntax (i.e. import and export).
- @babel/preset-env is configured with modules: false, other babel presets we use are @babel/preset-react and @babel/preset-typescript
- not sure if sideEffects should be set in package.json as we are not publishing the project as package, I am okay with third-party libraries not being tree-shaken. `optimization.sideEffects` should be true by default.
- production mode is enabled

Comment: Are you on webpack 4 or 5?

Comment: @TylerGraf, webpack 5